# JSON assertion failing in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

On sending an incorrect username/password, the server application sends this JSON:

```
{"result":"error","additional-info":"Incorrect username or password"}
```

I have made the assertion:

[image]

Server sends:

[image]

But the `tree viewer` seems to indicate that there is an error. The response log file has this message

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1606209008151,39,SignInRequest,401,Unauthorized,SignInUsers 1-1,text,**false**,**path can not be null or empty**,570,263,1,1,http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signin,37,0,21
```

What am I doing wrong in asserting the response?

UPDATE
I added `json assertion` but when I run the test, the screen looks like this (red color but not sure what the reason is)

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, if I change the validation from `error` to `"error"` then I can see reason (kind of expandable tree) which when using just `error` doesn't appear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare the full response - you need to go for [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved).

[image]

however it's very sensitive to any changes, a whitespace or line break will cause the failure.

---

JSON Assertion allows executing arbitrary [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries, so if you want to assert `additional-info` element you should go for something like:

[image]

and this one is for `result`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the test is still failing. Unfortunately, I can't find the reason for the failure. I have updated the question

Comment: I had to check `ignore status`. Also, I think some other bits were also wrong in the way I organised the requests and assertions. More details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65042641/how-to-test-that-server-returns-401/65044682#65044682

Answer (score 0):

You are validating the expected results, so you don't fail

Check [Invert assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) checkbox if you want it to fail (or change to success response)

> Invert assertion (will fail if above conditions met) Invert assertion (will fail if above conditions met)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. The way the test case is at the moment, has the test case passed. I think it hasn't because the `SignInRequest` is in red color.

Comment: Doesn't this line mean that the test ha failed - `**false**,**path can not be null or empty**`

Comment: @ManuChadha In JSON you must set JSON expression path, as `$.result` and then you can assert the value as `error`