# How to test that server returns 401

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to create a `jmeter` test which should pass if the server returns `401`. I also want to test that the message body contains a `json`.

I have done this so far

[image]

[image]

[image]

But the test case is failing. Why?

[image]

UPDATE
I thought I should use `ignore status` in `response assertion` but then the test color comes up as both green and red if the `json` body doesn't match. I am confused what is happening and whether the test has passed or not.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was doing several things wrong.

1. First, the assertions should have been children of the request.
2. The response assertion should check response code as `401` but `ignore status` should also be checked otherwise `jmeter` interprets the message as error

"Ignore Status : Checking this checkbox tells JMeter to not mark in error a page that returns a response code that it considers in error (Anything different from 2XX, 3XX). This is useful when you know a request should fail in a certain way and you want to check it does"

[image]